# jstl forEach iterate with no certain number of steps

Tags: foreach, jstl

I want to create a forEach that begin at 0 and ends at count; that variable count can change inside loop. I set count to 4 than, inside loop change it to 8 but that didn't change number of loops.

```
<c:set var="count" value="4"></c:set>
        <c:forEach begin="0" end="${count}">
            <c:out value="message"></c:out>
            <c:if test="${count < 6}">
                <c:set var="count" value="8"/>
            </c:if>

        </c:forEach>
```

Result: message five time, expected 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this.

Because JSTL is converted to java code finally, the interpreter would directly take the value of the count when reached to the line. Thus, it is equivalent to:

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="4">
...
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: That's a shame. I was afraid that this would be the answer but I thought maybe I was wrong. Is there a workaround to do what I want?